# MySQL NodeJS .then() s not a function

Tags: mysql, node.js, promise

Can't I use promise for nodeJS mysql query?

```
// My DB settings
const db = require('../util/database');

db.query(sqlQuery, [param1, param2])
        .then(result => {
            console.log(result);
        })
        .catch(err => {
            throw err;
        });
```

It is returning: `TypeError: db.query(...).then is not a function`

Comment: This will only work if the underlying function for `db.query` is using a promise or async/await. Otherwise, you can wrap your `db.query` command with its own promise and resolve the results when it completes

Comment: Mysqljs uses callbacks, not promises. ".then()" is for promises. Instead, you will want to use: db.query(sqlQuery, function (error, results, fields) { ... })

Comment: Thanks. The problem with function(error, results, fields) is that it executes the next line without awaiting finish the process inside this function

Comment: That is correct. You could put that logic inside of the callback, which can be less than ideal at times, especially when your inner logic contains other methods that contain callbacks, also known as callback hell.

Alternatively, you could wrap the db.query block with a promise as @chrisbyte suggested. I will post this as an answer now.

Comment: Does anyone know why I received a downvote? I thought it was a normal question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mentioned in the comments that you want logic after the query block to be awaited, without placing that logic inside of the callback. By wrapping the method with a Promise, you can do that as such:

```
try {
    const result = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        db.query(sqlQuery, (error, results, fields) => {
            if (error) return reject(error);
            return resolve(results);
        });
    });

    //do stuff with result
} catch (err) {
    //query threw an error
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work

```
function runQuery(sqlQuery){
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      db.query(sqlQuery, function(error, results, fields) {
          if (error) reject(error);
          else resolve(results);
      });
  });
}

// test
runQuery(sqlQuery)
    .then(function(results) {
        console.log(results)
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        throw error;
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

`mysql` package does not support promise. We can use `then` only a function call returns a promise.You can use `mysql2` which has inbuilt support for **Promise**. It will also make your code more readable. From mysql2 docs:

```
 async function main() {
        // get the client
          const mysql = require('mysql2/promise');
         // create the connection
         const connection = await mysql.createConnection({host:'localhost', 
          user: 'root', database: 'test'});
          // query database
          const [rows, fields] = await connection.execute(query);
          // rows hold the result
        }
```

I would aslo recommend you to learn about callbacks, promise and async-await